# Matrice 210 - "ESC ERROR", red/yellow flashing light on motor

Tags: dji-sdk

We've never seen this before, and search returns almost no instances of this error online.

The problem is, one motor won't spin upon start-up or spin when attempting flight with the RC. It blinks red/yellow on the LED constantly. On the CrystalSky tablet, when we try to fly, it says "ESC ERROR".

The only thing we did different to this motor was unscrewed/screwed a tiny screw on the bottom of the motor.

To fix this, we re-uploaded the firmware to the drone. We also re-uploaded the firmware to the RC. We've also plugged in DJI Assistant, which does not show an error.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware issue with the drone itself.  I would recommend contacting DJI Customer Support.